# Are there real life cases when C4129 warning does not indicate an error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

Visual C++ has [C4129 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew69e79d.aspx) that is emitted on code like the following:

```
cout << "\n\Nothing to do\n\n";
```

Here it's not really clear what the intent was - perhaps it should be `\n\n` at the start of the string  or perhaps it should be a single `\n` and the second slash should not be there so this code hardly does what its author wanted.

This is why I'd rather change this warning into error in our codebase.

Are there any real life cases when this warning is emitted for perfectly correct code?

Comment: In regular expressions, `\\` escapes special characters which makes them easier to read unambiguously. For example, '-' has a special meaning within character classes, but not outside. Therefore, it might be more readable to escape it when using it outside. Perhaps a similar use case might be applicable to general C++ strings.

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot: Wouldn't I need to type that as `\\-` instead of `\-`?

Comment: I think that C++11 raw string literals would make `\-` possible.

Comment: @sharptooth: yes you would.

Comment: On the other hand, the compiler maybe wouldn't emit that warning in a raw string.

Comment: It is a level 1 warning, you never ignore them.  Everybody has that turned on, the number of questions about "MSVC warns about a valid escape sequence!" are zero.

Comment: @HansPassant: This didn't prevent me from finding a project with `/W3` and the code cited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undefined behavior in older versions of C++ (pre-C++11),
and is now "conditionally-supported" behavior (which means that
if it is supported, the compiler must document it).  The only
case where `"\N"` wouldn't be an error in the code is when it
actually targets a specific compiler extension.

I can very easily imagine a compiler treating `"\N"` like
`"\n"`, although I can't see any reason to use this feature.
(On the other hand, I can also imagine a compiler using `"\e"`
for the ESC characters, and code using this feature when
portability isn't an issue.)

From a quality of implementation point of view, I would expect
an error unless the compiler actually does implement something
defined (as an extension).

Answer (score 3):

It is *implementation-defined* what `"\N"` means, so it is up to the implementation to reject or accept such a program. That means that in a portable standard-conforming program there is no valid meaning for `\N` and it cannot be anything but an error. More strict compilers may actually reject this code with an error.

Comment: In pre-C++11, it's undefined behavior (which an implementation can define).  So while from a QoI point of view, one would expect an error, poorer compilers may emit just a warning, or nothing at all, and still be conforming.  In C++11, the behavior must be documented, and the compiler must issue a diagnostic (which traditionally means an error) if the sequence is not supported.  (Formally, it's _conditionally-supported_, and not _implementation-defined_, but I don't see where that distinction makes a difference here.)